# Detect UILabel line break. Place items into UITableViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, line-breaks

I would like to detect after fill up multiple `UILabel` included in each `UITableViewCell` of a `UITableView` if there is a way to detect if the `UILabel` has a Line Break. Because of I'd like  set its frame dynamically. I need to do it because I have an `UILabel` in top of another and the UILabel thats below the other has to have the the same distance from the other for each row.

I only found the property `numberOfLines` of a `UILabel` and I realized that depending of the device (iPhone 6, 6 Plus and the rest), the width of the `UITableViewCell` changes. So it affects directly to the `UILabel` space. I could calculate the length of the `UILabel` and depending of it, change the frame of the `UILabel` thats below depending of this length but I dont like this way.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to detect the line break to do this. You should use auto layout. You should set a vertical spacing constraint between the bottom of the top label and the top of the bottom label -- that will give them a fixed spacing no matter what size the labels expand to.

Comment: Ok, and which types of constraints have I to add to the rest of elements of the View of the UITableViewCell. Because using the Add missing constraints helping mode of Xcode just screws everything up.

Comment: @santibernaldo, You need constraints that go from the top of the cell through any views that are over top of each other to the bottom of the cell - so a chain of constraints that connect the top and bottom of the cell with views and spaces.

Comment: I fixed with your comments, thanks rdelmar. Sorry for not replying before!

Answer (score 1):

i would try testing the height of the given text with a given font. In this way you will know how many lines the text occupy (of course, also if there is a line break **but you will dont know where**). At first you have to calculate the size of the text:

```
CGRect rect = [yourStrign boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(yourLabelWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: yourFont}
                                       context:nil];
```

Now, for know the number of lines you just need to make a division:

```
return ceil(rect.size.height / yourFont.lineHeight);
```